# Exposing episerver content as a services to third party application

Tags: episerver

I'm  using latest episerver 11 CMS. Is it possible to expose Service From Episerver ? If yes ...Kindly suggest. I need to expose episerver content as service.

Answer (score 2):

Numerous ways, but you can add the Content Delivery API NuGet package: https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/content-delivery-api/

Comment: Thanks Ted. I will go through it. But I would like to know other alternative as well.
Is it possible without any nuget package ?

Comment: Best approach depends on your requirements, but you could for example create action methods on your page controllers to return JSON instead of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EPiserver FIND all the content is already index and ready to be shared. ContentDeliveryApi just takes that data and outputs it in a meaningful way. It also requires minimal effort.  You can always create your own restful Web API and share whatever content you require